# Android - How to access sqlite database from internal memory phone?

Tags: android, sqlite, root

I've created an app using Eclipse + ADT that reads and write into a sqlite db, it works fine on Android terminal emulator, but, running from the phone itself, it does not populate the Spinners from db, which means it does not locate db in internal memory, I already checked with adb shell if the db is on the phone and it's there, so I guess I need to give root permissions to the app to allow it to use the db, how can I do this? my phone is a Motorola Defy and it's rooted, thanks in advanced, have a nice day.

EDIT: This is my class to create the table and adds the methods onCreate and onUpdate:

```
public class passwordSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

String SqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE password(id INTEGER, name TEXT, password TEXT)";

public passwordSQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(SqlCreate);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS password");
    db.execSQL(SqlCreate);

}

}
```

And I'm calling it from the main class when the activity starts:

```
passwordSQLiteHelper passUserDb = new passwordSQLiteHelper(this, "/data/data/com.project.otto/databases/password", null, 1);
```

On the terminal works great, but not on the phone where seems like it can't find the db, I checked with adb and it's there, please help me out, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to store the database outside of application storage?

Comment: Is it your app's DB? Then you don't need root.

Comment: Post code and any errors you can see in logcat. As Pulsar says, your own app doesn't need any special permissions to work with its own DB in internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't specify the full path to the database in the constructor.  Just the filename should be fine (since Android will automatically create it in your applications private data area).

```
public PasswordDatabase(Context context {
    super(context, "password.db", null, 1);
}
```

And create it via:

```
PasswordDatabase db = new PasswordDatabase(this);
```

If you look at the docs for [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29), it states that the database will not be created until either `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` are called.  So, I'd try calling one of those methods and then check that the database was created.

Comment: I did not specify the fullpath at the beginning, but I tried with it just to make sure, but, why does it work when using the emulator, and it does not show anything from the db when running on the phone?

Comment: I already tried your code, and the result is the same, but it's still working on the terminal emulator, don't know what's happening, thanks in advanced!

Comment: I got it, it was my mistake all the time, the table on my phone was not populated with data, while the one in the emulator was, I thought that the database created on the emulator was transfered by Eclipse into the phone as well, thanks a lot for trying to help me, I'm new with Eclipse and Android programming, have a nice day!